# SQL - INSERT text into field WHERE ___

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to add a note to each of my accounts whenever I make contact via a mass email. I'm looking at something like this so far:

```
INSERT INTO Customer_notes (Note_text)
VALUES ('emailed June 1st')
WHERE Customer_Level = 'Alpha'
```

This obviously doesn't work, and UPDATE/SET will replace all of my previous notes.

Comment: Please post your table structure, what database engine you are working with (SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)

Comment: I'm using MSSQL

Structure is: (customer_number, Note_date, user_id, Note_text)

Comment: @GraemeMartin Please post the table structure.

Comment: `INSERT` for for inserting a new record into database.  If the record already exists, use `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Customer_notes (Note_text)
    Note_Text = COALESCE(Note_text + '
', '') + 'emailed June 1st')
    WHERE Customer_Level = 'Alpha';
```

However, it seems like you need more than one note per customer.  So perhaps:

```
INSERT INTO Customer_notes (Customer_Level, Note_text)
    VALUES ('Alpha', Note_Text);
```

This is assuming that `Customer_Level` is some sort of customer id.

Comment: Customers have their own unique ID, the customer_level refers to the pricing tier that they are on so it would affect multiple. We add notes through a GUI under note_text each time we make contact with each customer - but I'm looking for a way to add 'MASS EMAIL' to ALL customers of that pricing tier...

Answer (score 1):

If you mean add that text to whatever currently exists in Note_text for existing rows, then try this..

```
UPDATE Customer_notes
SET Note_text = ISNULL(Note_text, '') + ' emailed June 1st'
WHERE Customer_Level = 'Alpha'
```

{edit based on the fifth comment in this answer}

Ok, then instead of VALUES we are SELECTing off of the same table.  Try this (Holy Gawd make a backup first) if the idea is to create another row with EVERY row WHERE Customer_Level = 'Alpha' in this table.

```html
INSERT INTO Customer_Notes (CustomerID, note_text) 
SELECT CustomerID, 'emailed June 1st'
FROM CustomerNotes
WHERE Customer_Level = 'Alpha'
```

This does beg the question if Customer_Level is a subset of all customers, and if the idea here is to only insert one row for EACH of these customers, as opposed to ONE row for each customber/existing rows.  You'll have to describe this further for us if this is the case.

Comment: All note_text are not null - I don't want to edit/update current notes, but rather add a new one into that column.

Comment: You'll have to define this further.  INSERT = Add a new row to this tables with stated values.  UPDATE = Change the values in existing rows.  Reading the question is was not clear which you were trying to do, especially as there is no such animal as INSERT .. VALUES .. WHERE, as INSERT implies a new row and WHERE implies existing rows.

Comment: Ok. I have a field in a table called 'note_text' in which we can add notes attached to a customer via their customer ID. I am looking for a way to add a new note to all customers that have an identical tag.

Comment: Ok, so assuming that this table can handle multiple notes for an existing customer that that would go something like INSERT INTO Customer_Notes (CustomerID, note_text) VALUES (the customer number, 'emailed June 1st').  Define 'identical tag' for us.

Comment: Gladly. Identical tag would be like a tier of customers.So for example I could have:

Customer (john doe)
Note Text (contacted may 23, contacted june 1st)
Customer Tier (Alpha)

So I want to add note_text where customer tier = alpha to add the identical note to all alpha tier customers.

Comment: ^^^ Updated answer based on this comment.